# Is there a way to transfer Overwatch skins between PS4/Xbox One/PC?

Tags: overwatch

I have played a ton of Overwatch on console and am now am looking to make the most of my PC and play Overwatch there. Is there a way to transfer skins from console to PC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, it is not possible to transfer any skins/emotes/highlight intros/sprays/currency from console to PC. This is due to Microsoft and Sony having their own network that you have to play OW on - Blizzard does not directly control user accounts on that network, so there's no way for them to access the stuff you already have.

Comment: Technically Blizzard still has the user IDs of Live and PSN accounts, so *technically* it's possible- it's more to do with licence agreements between Microsoft/Sony & Blizzard.